# How to divert traffic to my back-up website when my site is down?

Tags: php, backup

I have created a PHP website. I already have a shared hosting and bought a new VPS. Now I want to launch my website from my new VPS, but I want to keep a mirror running on my shared hosting and in case if my VPS goes down, I want the traffic to be diverted to my shared hosting for the time being. I am totally new to this and have no idea how can I do this and dont know if this should be posted on Server fault or here.

I tried to google about this, but I am not able to find anything like this. Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a load balancer or proxy which can route your request to a different node when one node goes down. Basically your DNS entries will point to the proxy, which will transparently forward requests to the correct node.

There are some turn-key load balancers out there which are really simple to set up. [Rackspace Cloud Load Balancers](http://www.rackspace.com/cloud/cloud_hosting_products/loadbalancers/) are the first that come to mind.

Answer (score 1):

I cant explain it but I can point you to some resources that can:

http://library.linode.com/linux-ha

Linode is a hosting company I use for VPS and they have a nice and extensive library of tutorials.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In the load balancer example they are using about 5 linodes, which would be costly for me at this moment of time.